# Error: Unexpected '@' in program

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting the following error.

Unexpected '@' in program.

My code is as follows:

```
SKTexture* eyeTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"eye1"];
eyeTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKTexture* eyeTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"eye2"];
eyeTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    SKAction* flap = [SKAction repeatActionForever: [SKAction animateWithTextures:@[eyeTexture1,      eyeTexture2] timePerFrame:0.2]];

_eye = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:eyeTexture1];
[_eye setScale:2.0];
_eye.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 4, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[_eye runAction:flap];

}
@end //this is where the error occurs.
```

I've checked the other answers on here, but they do not solve my issue.
Thanks

EDIT: In response, the code is within an @implementation, I could not add any more code due to stack overflow's "More Code, More Detail" thing. There is a curly bracket that opens this.

Comment: Where is this code? within a method? within a `@implementation`? please post more code to give overall scope of the class.

Comment: You probably have curly bracket open and did not close it. That should be in one of the methods before the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that your code has @`implementation` defined and that you have not deleted/commented that line accidentally.  Also check that there is no code after `@end`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a matching "`@implementation`" at the top of your .m file.

E.G.:

```
@implementation MyGameCode

…
…
…

@end
```